# Moving train in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

There's a keyboard shortcut I hit by mistake on vscode and there was a moving train; Please, I need that train, does anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Er.. Do you mean a literal train? A series of connected railroad cars pulled or pushed by one or more locomotives? Like an Easter Egg?

Comment: Hey, so I found the solution. Apparently the train is not on VSCode but on the linux terminal. See link https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/displays-animations-when-accidentally-you-type-sl-instead-of-ls.html .. The train comes when you run confuse list command ls with sl.